Как в React приложении в режиме React.StrictMode заставить работать JavaScript API Яндекс Карты 3.0?
Согласно документации:
Документация
Добавляю в React приложение Яндекс Карту и приложение уходит в ошибки:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'coordinates')

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')

The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef> component:

и д.р.
Но когда убираю React.StrictMode приложение запускается без ошибок и яндекс карты отображаются.





import {
  YMap,
  YMapDefaultSchemeLayer,
  YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer,
  YMapMarker,
  reactify
} from '../../lib/ymaps';
import type { YMapLocationRequest } from 'ymaps3';

const LOCATION: YMapLocationRequest = {
  center: [37.588144, 55.733842],
  zoom: 9
};

function Map() {
  return (
    <>
      <YMap location={reactify.useDefault(LOCATION)}>
        <YMapDefaultSchemeLayer />
        <YMapDefaultFeaturesLayer />

        <YMapMarker
          coordinates={reactify.useDefault([37.588144, 55.733842])}
          draggable={true}
        >
          <section>
            <h1>You can drag this header</h1>
          </section>
        </YMapMarker>
      </YMap>
    </>
  );
}

export default Map;




Покажите код, где возникает ошибка Cannot read properties of undefined

Обновил вопрос )

@СергейПермяков покажите весь код где используете coordinates и location не скриншотом, а как код.

Обновил вопрос, а именно добавил код, в котором похоже возникает ошибка... по крайней мере в других местах эти переменные не используются
